# Simple Codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having some problem in my login form like this

[image]

I want to display an individually error beside of each field

here is the controller

```
function index()
{      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|exact_length[4]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]|xss_clean|callback_login');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('jabatan','Jabatan','trim|required|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }

}

function login()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $jabatan = $this->input->post('jabatan');

    $value = $this->m_login->login($username,$password,$jabatan);

    if($value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('login', 'password salah');
        //delete redirect() and showing blank white screen
        return false;

    }
```

I made the `<?php echo form_error(); ?>` beside each field

```
<?php echo form_open('c_login/login'); ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><?php $inusername=array('name' => 'username', 'class' => 'GUI'); echo form_input($inusername); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><?php $inpassword=array('name' => 'password', 'class' => 'GUI', 'type' =>'password'); echo form_input($inpassword); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('password'); echo $this->session->flashdata('login'); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Jabatan</td>
                    <td><?php $injabatan=array('keuangan' => 'keuangan', 'admin' => 'admin', 'hd' => 'head divisi', 'direktur' => 'direktur'); echo form_dropdown('jabatan',$injabatan,'keuangan','class = "gui"'); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('jabatan'); ?></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php $insubmit=array('name' =>'login','class' =>'button','value' => 'Login'); echo form_submit($insubmit); echo nbs(); $inreset=array('name' =>'reset','class' =>'button','value' => 'Hapus'); echo form_reset($inreset); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

How come the `form_error()` function is not `echo`ing anything when I click login with the `username` and `password` field left blank?

Comment: Beacuse you aren't sending the error messages

Comment: @BhuvanRikka i read on http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#overview 'Showing Errors Individually' section. it looks like i have the same controller

Comment: hope my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you know problem in your validation you're checking validation in index method of your class not in login method of your class and in your form you have given action to ci_login/login method which is redirecting if login is failed and its clearing form validation validate your fields on login method also and put all error message in session and display, i have made some changes in script have look here on this link [Code modified](http://scrp.at/bPy)

for this changes you have to use url helper

```
function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|exact_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]|xss_clean|callback_login');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('jabatan','Jabatan','trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        //to check if the validation run correctly
        //$this->load->view('welcome_message');

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $jabatan = $this->input->post('jabatan');

        $value = $this->m_login->login($username,$password,$jabatan);

        if($value)
        {
            redirect('welcome_message');
            //return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('login', 'password salah');
            redirect('c_login',$login); //i want to pass $login into login form, then print
            return false;               //them as a form_error

        }
    }

}


<?php echo form_open(uri_string()); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><?php $inusername=array('name' => 'username', 'class' => 'GUI'); echo form_input($inusername); ?></td>
        <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php $inpassword=array('name' => 'password', 'class' => 'GUI', 'type' =>'password'); echo form_input($inpassword); ?></td>
        <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('password'); echo $this->session->flashdata('login'); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Jabatan</td>
        <td><?php $injabatan=array('keuangan' => 'keuangan', 'admin' => 'admin', 'hd' => 'head divisi', 'direktur' => 'direktur'); echo form_dropdown('jabatan',$injabatan,'keuangan','class = "gui"'); ?></td>
        <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('jabatan'); ?></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php $insubmit=array('name' =>'login','class' =>'button','value' => 'Login'); echo form_submit($insubmit); echo nbs(); $inreset=array('name' =>'reset','class' =>'button','value' => 'Hapus'); echo form_reset($inreset); ?></td>
        <td class="error"><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

### `index` will not execute when `login` does.

If appears that maybe you think the `set_rules()` functions will execute when you submit the form. They won't. The form will submit to `'c_login/login'`, which is the `login()` function inside your `c_login` controller.

You need to move your form validation logic into `login()`, and have `index()` just echo the view for the first time.

### Your Controller

```
function index(){      
    $this->load->view('login');
}

function login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|exact_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|xss_clean|correct');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('jabatan','Jabatan','trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        //your validation messages will be taken care of.
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{
        $p = $this->input->post();
        if($this->m_login->login($p['username'],$p['password'],$p['jabatan'])){
            //redirect() user to logged in area.
        }
        else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('login', 'password salah');
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be trimming passwords. The space character is a perfectly valid suffix or prefix in a password. I've removed `trim` for you. I've also removed the `min_length` and `max_length`. This is something you'd want to enforce on a signup page, are you sure it really adds any value on a login page?

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply form_error() with the field:

```
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
```

[See more details here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors)

Comment: i have corrected the code as your instruction, it doesn't shows any form_error information :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you have a big misunderstanding on how these things work. First of all, you don't need that `redirect()` call in `login()`. The `redirect()` functions will redirect the user to another page, and since neither CodeIgniter nor PHP keep an object between page requests, you'd lose everything (e.g. The form validation object and its error messages).

Also, you might want to prefix that `login()` method with an underscore (`_`), so that no one can access it through an HTTP request.

You should probably submit the form to the `index()` method instead of `login()`. Then, make sure you only run the validation on a `POST` request.

```
function index()
{
    if ($_POST)
    {
        // run validation here
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: i made it without `redirect()` and then, click the login button while leaving username and facebook field blank, the browser shows empty page. and i want to redirect them into login, so i use `redirect()` CMIIW

Comment: @Cignitor could you please update your post with the updated code? There might be something wrong with it that's causing the blank page.

Comment: i'm not sure if it has something to do with the models. would you want me to post my models ?

Comment: @Cignitor my bad. I forgot to look at the view code. You should probably submit the form to the `index()` method instead of `login()`. Then, make sure you only run the validation on a `POST` request.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Simple form validation, image upload and captcha using codeigniter libraries**
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Loginmodel');

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'uploadss/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'uploadss/',
            'font_path'     => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '200',
            'img_height'    => 90,
            'word_length'   => 3,
            'font_size'     => 25
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and set new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $captcha['word']);

        // Pass captcha image to view
        $fetch['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];

        $fetch['data'] = $this->Loginmodel->alldata();
        $this->load->view('login',$fetch);
    }

    public function loginerror()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','first name','required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('companyname', 'Companyname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('designation', 'Designation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('companysize', 'Companysize', 'required|numeric');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
            if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha)
            {
                echo 'Captcha code matched.';

                    $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
                    $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
                    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
                    $email = $this->input->post('email');
                    $password = $this->input->post('password');
                    $companyname = $this->input->post('companyname');
                    $designation = $this->input->post('designation');
                    $companysize = $this->input->post('companysize');

                    $checkmobile = $this->Loginmodel->checkmobile($mobile,$email);

                    if($checkmobile)
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Mobile Number or Email exist.....");
                        return redirect('Login/index'); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $insertdata = $this->Loginmodel->insert($fname,$lname,$mobile,$email,$password,$companyname,$designation,$companysize);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Record Inserted");
                        return redirect('Home/indexhome');
                    }   
                // }
                // else
                // {
                //  $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Please fill all the values properly");
                //  $this->index();
                // }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Captcha code does not match, please try again.';
                $this->index();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("danger","Please fill all the values properly");
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    public function refresh(){
        // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'uploadss/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'uploadss/',
            'font_path'     => base_url().'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '200',
            'img_height'    => 90,
            'word_length'   => 3,
            'font_size'     => 25
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

        echo $captcha['image'];
    }

    public function upload($id)
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['imagename']['name']))
        {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploadss/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['imagename']['name'];

                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('imagename'))
                {
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $imagename = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "not upload";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
        $this->load->view('uploadimage');
    }

    public function uploadimageerror()
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['imagename']['name']))
        {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploadss/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['imagename']['name'];

                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('imagename'))
                {
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $imagename = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "not upload";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
    }

    public function deletedata($id)
    {
        $dele = $this->Loginmodel->delete($id);
        return redirect('Login/index');
    }
}
?>
```