# Validate Front End Form Using Codeigniter Validation

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-validation

I hope you are doing well.

I was wondering that is there any way to validate front end validation using codeigniter?

Basically I want to validate client side & server side validation using codeingiter.

Let me know if there's any pretty library or something.

I have searched on Internet and end up here to ask experts. :)

Many Thanks,

Muhammad Ahsan Ali

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axtmWvdFdDk

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832491/simple-codeigniter-form-validation

Comment: I want to set rules from back end and apply on front end as well by using any jquery library like: formvalidator.net

Answer (score 0):

here is CI library with example!

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

A video link to understand
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axtmWvdFdDk

to custom rules 
https://arjunphp.com/custom-validation-rules-codeigniter/

Comment: I want to set rules from back end and apply on front end as well by using any jquery library like: 

http://www.formvalidator.net/

Comment: you can set your custom rules as well !
https://arjunphp.com/custom-validation-rules-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

> Check out this Code to make Ajax serve side validation showing in Client side
>   [Ajax Validation in Codeigniter using Ajax](https://github.com/eboominathan/ajax_crud_datatables_with_validation)